# Self Hosted (Owin) based Asp.Net Web API on Windows 10 mobile phone

Tags: c#, windows, rest, asp.net-web-api, windows-mobile

Is it possible to run Self Hosted (Owin) based Asp.Net Web API on Windows 10 mobile phone/tablet?
I would like to use mobile/tablet as a server for Asp.Net Web API which I already developed.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Since Windows 10 Mobile features a "device portal", which comprises  a set of REST resources which are located in the network at the device IP, an answer seems to be "yes, is possible". But I'm afraid this facility is implemented as a (sort-of) modified WCF service. It doesn't need a regular HTTP server, which would be overkill for a resource-constrained device, but emits HTTP documents in response to REST requests. Perhaps you can design your own, keeping in mind that the concept of "service" is not available in Windows Mobile. In order to avoid keeping your app in foreground, you must perform some little research on "background tasks" in UWP, documentation was refreshed a couple of weeks ago (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks)
However, these ones seem to be designed for lightweight applications. But *perhaps* you could design an HTTP listener in your application, generate the  required documents and return them to the caller. I'm pretty sure that Project Katana cannot be included in an UWP solution, but I would recommend a quick reading on the subject as well.

Comment: Surely I will study the link in detail. Not sure why windows 10 has such limitations for mobile devices. I have seen many tiny server apps(Http Sever and Ftp server) running on android OS. So I thought similar facility would be available on Windows 10 for mobile devices.